# How to combine values inside a common column from two different tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Sorry if the title is confusing, since English isn't my first language. But I'll try to describe my tables thoroughly.

I have 3 tables inside my database named: Restaurant1, Restaurant2, and ItemList

Tables Restaurant 1 and Restaurant 2 both contain two columns named: PID(product ID), and QTY(quantity)

ItemList table contains three columns named: PID(product ID as well), Product, and supID (supplier ID)

Here is the visualization:

**Restaurant1:**

```
   PID           QTY
=========   ============
p01           1
p04           5 
p06           4
p10           4          
p12           1
p14           6
```

**Restaurant2:**

```
   PID           QTY
=========   ============
p04           5
p09           4 
p13           3
```

**ItemLIst:**

```
   PID           Product    supID
=========   ============    ======
p01           Beef Steak      mla1        
.             Beef Cutlet     mla2
.             Pork Steak      .
.             Whole Chicken   .
.              .              .
.              .              .
              and so on...    mla15
p15
```

The supID column isn't relevant for this question since what I want know is how I could combine Restaurant 1 and Restaurant 2 like this:

**Restaurant 1 and 2 (combined):**

```
   PID           QTY
=========   ============
p01           1
p04           5 
p06           4
p10           4          
p12           1
p14           6
p04           5
p09           4 
p13           3
```

In short... I want to literally combine the values of the two table into one table. But I want to use only the JOIN clause such as inner join, outer join, etc.

This is what I've tried that didn't work and I don't know what other solutions I could do.

```
SELECT ItemList.PID, Restaurant1.QTY, Restaurant2.QTY FROM ItemList
    -> OUTER JOIN Restaurant1 ON ItemList.PID=Restaurant1.PID
    -> OUTER JOIN Restaurant2 ON ItemList.PID=Restaurant2.PID;
```

I tried different combinations such as using LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN, but it gives me different output.

Hope some could help.

EDIT: I don't want to make another table. Instead, I just want to display it the way I showed it. In which, the combined list of products and quantities from both tables Restaurant1 and Restaurant2 are displayed.

Comment: In your example p04=5 in both restaurants, and in the combined table.  What do you want to have in the combined table when the two restaurants have different numbers of the same product?

Comment: @rd_nielsen it's fine for me since they are products of different restaurants, but sure, it would be better if their quantities are added

Comment: I suggest having just one restaurant table with 3 columns: restaurant_id, product_id and quantity.

Comment: Your example is not useful. Please make p04 qty different in each restaurant and show the new p04 result with an explanation of how the result is calculated

Answer (score 0):

Union the two tables, then sum the quantity, grouping by the product:

```
select PID, sum(QTY) as QTY
from (
   select PID, QTY from Restaurant1
   union all
   select PID, QTY from Restaurant2
   ) as r
group by PID;
```

Comment: In real world it is ok to have the same quantity of some product in two different locations, which is not allowed in case of `union`: it removes duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `UNION ALL` both tables to get all rows after that you can sum the quantity up

But it would be simpler to have pone one table with all restaurants and a new column will show which restaurants has the quantoty,.

That is also a good idea because you can only union a certain quantity of taböes

> ```
> CREATE TABLE restaurant1 (
>   `PID` VARCHAR(3),
>   `QTY` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO restaurant1
>   (`PID`, `QTY`)
> VALUES
>   ('p01', '1'),
>   ('p04', '5'),
>   ('p06', '4'),
>   ('p10', '4'),
>   ('p12', '1'),
>   ('p14', '6');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE restaurant2 (
>   `PID` VARCHAR(3),
>   `QTY` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO restaurant2
>   (`PID`, `QTY`)
> VALUES
>   ('p04', '5'),
>   ('p09', '4'),
>   ('p13', '3');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> `PID`, SUM(`QTY`) Qty_both
> FROM
> (SELECT * FROM restaurant1
> UNION ALL
> SELECT * FROM restaurant2) t1
> GROUP BY `PID`
> ORDER BY `PID`
> ```
>
> ```
> PID | Qty_both
> :-- | -------:
> p01 |        1
> p04 |       10
> p06 |        4
> p09 |        4
> p10 |        4
> p12 |        1
> p13 |        3
> p14 |        6
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5316ee3a061a449068300048eacbfcb0)*